# JQuery implementing if statement issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to put an if statement in the following code. But since I am new at JQuery, I don't know how to put it there. When I uncomment the lines, I am getting an "missing : after property id" error on FireBug. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```
$( ".droppable" ).droppable({
  //if ((this.firstChild) != "[object HTMLImageElement]") {
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var dropped = ui.draggable;
      var droppedOn = $(this);
      $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
  //}
});
```

Comment: You cannot write if statement over drop. That is the place for options. Put it inside drop.

Comment: *if* is a conditional statement so logically speaking *if* can be a part of any coding block so you may use in **function(event,ui){....}**

Answer (score 0):

You can't have code in an object literal.

Create the object first, then optionally add the property:

```
var o = {};
if ((this.firstChild) != "[object HTMLImageElement]") {
  o.drop = function( event, ui ) {
    var dropped = ui.draggable;
    var droppedOn = $(this);
    $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
  };
}
$( ".droppable" ).droppable(o);
```

#### Edit:

If you need to use `this` from inside the function, then the entire approach is wrong. The object always has to have the property, and you have to do the check inside the function instead:

```
$( ".droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    if ((this.firstChild) != "[object HTMLImageElement]") {
      var dropped = ui.draggable;
      var droppedOn = $(this);
      $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it didn't change anything. It works as if there is no if statement. I guess that's because I need the object "this" of the drop function.

Comment: @Semih: This code works exactly as the original code would do if using code inside an object literal was possible. If you need `this` from inside the function, then the entire approach is wrong, the object always has to have the property, and you have to do the check inside the function instead.

Comment: But in this case, drop action is already happening before checking the if statement. I don't know if what I want is possible, but I want to execute the drop function according to the result of the if statement.